# Django newbie and tutorial

Tags: django

I'm a complete Django newbie and I am following the tutorial:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/intro/tutorial01/

I have got to the stage:

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
url(r'^polls/', include('polls.urls')),
url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

in mysite/urls.py, but when I do:

```
python manage.py runserver
```

I get a 404 error in the browser at the address

```
http://localhost:8000/polls/
```

I am using python 2.7.6 and Django 1.11.5

My urls.py is

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^polls/', include('polls.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

In the terminal session I get

```
Not Found: /polls/
[05/Oct/2017 12:25:22] "GET /polls/ HTTP/1.1" 404 1951
```

when I load the web page in the browser

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'polls',
]
```

Can someone please point out what might be wrong?

Comment: What's in polls/urls.py?

Comment: please post your urls.py

Comment: @Psionman -  Hope you added  `polls` under INSTALLED_APPS in the `settings.py`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

on `mysite/settings.py` add in `INSTALLED_APPS`:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...<other installed apps>..
    'polls',
]
```

for latest django versions it is recommeded to add:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...<other installed apps>..
    'polls.apps.PollsConfig',
]
```

Put in `mysite/urls.py`(the one you posted here):

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin    
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^polls/', include('polls.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

And in `polls/urls.py`::

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views    
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
]
```

Comment: Thanks. just adding 'polls' does nothing. There is no PollsAuthConfig class in polls.apps, but there is PollsConfig. If I include PollsConfig it gives "application labels aren't unique ..." error

Comment: @Psionman what is `polls/urls.py`, you have posted here is `mysite/urls.py`

Comment: No. That is in .../polls/

Comment: OK. Solved it thanks. Didn't realise there were two urls.py (confusing for a newbie)

Answer (score 0):

clear answer  for beginners who has this issue by following the tutorial [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/intro/tutorial01/), the project root URLconf is the one in the same folder as `settings.py` which is:

```
mysite/mysite/urls.py
```

Just make sure `import 'include'`. The code looks like:

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^polls/', include('polls.urls')),
]
```

So in mysite/mysite/settings.py:

The line should be:

```
ROOT_URLCONF = 'mysite.urls'
```

You don't need create a fresh new root URLconf.